# QTreeWidgetItem editingFinished() signal?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a `QTreeWidget` with some items in it. However, due to my data structure, I need to have the `QTreeWidget` (or the `QTreeWidgetItem`) tell me when someone finishes editing it.

I already have a subclass of both `QTreeWidget` and `QTreeWidgetItem`, if that makes it any easier to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the QTreeWidget emits the signal `QTreeWidget::itemChanged ( QTreeWidgetItem * item, int column )`. this should do the job.

the thing is, it will also be called when you fill or change the tree from your code. therefor use the `QObject::blockSignals(bool)` to solve that.

soo long zai

Comment: Yes, how do you manage to catch the itemChanged when you editing someting and make no change just press enter ? In my case, I manage to use treeitem to create a file browser. when I want I can create a new folder, I'm creating a new item and detecting the itemChanged to catch the new name and create the folder on the filesystem. By default, the new folder is called 'new folder' and if you want to just press enter or esc to keep the default name, it failed to triggered the itemChanged as nothing changed.

Comment: might be because the item itself did not change; you could try to check for a `keyPressEvent` and emit a signal when `enter/return` is pressed

Comment: This solution is valid, but if I am changing items from many different methods this can be really tedious. On top of that, it is possible that the code was not made by me and when I create a new method I do not know that I have to blockSignals();.